# Read multiple images from directory in OpenCV (C++)

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am trying to read all the images from a directory in `OpenCV`. I using `videocapture` for it with the following reference [How to read multiple images from a folder in open cv (using C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628196/how-to-read-multiple-images-from-a-folder-in-open-cv-using-c). If I am doing:

```
VideoCapture cap("c:/fullpath/Image_001.png"); // for Image_001.png, etc. This is working.
while( cap.isOpened() )
{
    Mat frame;
    cap.read(frame);
// process(img);
}
```

it works but if I do:

```
VideoCapture cap("c:/fullpath/Image_%03d.png"); // for Image_001.png, etc. This doesn't works.
 while( cap.isOpened() )
 {
    Mat frame;
    cap.read(frame);
    // process(img);
 }
```

then it shows me the following error:

```
WARNING: Couldn't read movie file c:/fullpath/Image_%03d.png
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: use dirent.h and sort the string output

Comment: I already found a solution, will post it as as I am free. Thanks!

Comment: hi, mind to share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

From the tests I have done, it seems that OpenCV looks for the first image in the sequence, starting with Image_000.png. It doesn't work if the images are not sequentially numbered starting from 000.