# C++ OpenCV linear algebra on multiple images?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I am very new to C++ and OpenCV but more familiar with Matlab. I have a task that I need to move to C++ for faster processing. So I would like to ask for your suggestion on a image processing problem. I have 10 images in a folder and I was able to read them all using dirent.h like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628196/how-to-read-multiple-images-from-a-folder-in-open-cv-using-c) and extract each frame by calling `frame[count] = rawImage` in a while loop:

```
int count = 0;
std::vector<cv::Mat> frames;
frames.resize(10);
while((_dirent = readdir(directory)) != NULL)
{
    std::string fileName = inputDirectory + "\\" +std::string(_dirent->d_name);
    cv::Mat rawImage = cv::imread(fileName.c_str(),CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    frames[count] = rawImage; // Insert the rawImage to frames (this is original images)
    count++;
}
```

Now I want to access each frames and do calculation similar to Matlab to get another matrix `A` such that `A = frames(:,:,1)+2*frames(:,:,2)`. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `frames` is a `std::vector<cv::Mat>`, you should be able to access each `Mat` this way:

```
// suppose you want the nth matrix
cv::Mat frame_n = frames[n];
```

Now, if you want to do the calculation you said on the first two `Mat`s, then:

```
cv::Mat A = frames[0] + 2 * frames[1];
```

---

#### Example:

```
// mat1 = [[1 1 1]
//         [2 2 2]
//         [3 3 3]]
cv::Mat mat1 = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3);
cv::Mat mat2 = mat1 * 2; // multiplication matrix x scalar

// just to look like your case
std::vector<cv::Mat> frames;
frames.push_back(mat1);
frames.push_back(mat2);

cv::Mat A = frames[0] + 2 * frames[1]; // your calculation works
// A = [[ 5  5  5]
//      [10 10 10]
//      [15 15 15]]
```

You can always read the list of [acceptable expressions](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions).

Comment: Thank you very much Berriel